# 404 in Help Center for bounties

Tags: bug, status-completed, 404-not-found, help-center

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/whats-reputation):

> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: +1/2 of the bounty amount ([see more details about how bounties work](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/bounties))

The link does not work, shoud be `https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/bounty`.

Comment: Wait a moment...does that qualify as pluralization bug?!